# how to automate the logins on puttycm?

Tags: putty, openssh

I got puttyCm, I need to log in to my devices for once and let the putty store it..later i can come and enter automatically with out entering the passwords again?
can u show me the way pls?
in addition,
if one device can be reached thru other devices..how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below procedure (I assume that you have already engaged your puttycm with corresponding putty.exe or equivalent):

1. Just open any of your desired putty window by telnet or ssh (no need to login)
2. Right click on that window and click 'Configuration'; a window should pop up for same
3. In its 'Connection' tab on left side you can see check box called 'Enable Login macro mode'; select that
4. Now click on the tab 'Login Macro' again on left side; you can see Login / Password etc. fill them correctly (if you want to see the password which you type, you can click an EYE symbol next to it; that makes it visible until clicked again)
5. Once you login, if you want to enable some 'Post-login command' then check that box too; now you can write commands like 'bash' or 'myscript' etc in those command rows
6. Click 'OK' and verify by opening new windows (ctrl + u) of same ip addresses

Comment: The next time when you open the cm after closing, these macros will be wiped away.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with puttycm, but my Putty experience tells me that puttyagent that comes with putty is an answer for your question.

Putty-agent stores any private keys you provide to it and uses them for automated authorization. Private-key can be added by means of standard [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) tools like ssh-add or can be browsed to with GUI.